# Setup InnerException with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, moq, xunit

I am trying to `Setup() InnerException` using `Moq` in my unit tests.

```
var exceptionMock = new Mock<Exception>();

exceptionMock.Setup(e => e.InnerException)
                .Returns(new Exception());
```

But I am getting this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: e => e.InnerException
Non-overridable members (here: Exception.get_InnerException) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'
```

I guess it is because `InnerException` is not a `virtual` property.

How to setup `InnerException` for any `Exception` using `Moq` in unit tests?

Comment: Yep, you can't mock this as it's not an interface / virtual stuff. However, you can create some kind of `class TestException : Exception`. And use it like a normal Exception, since it is one, and setup whatever you want that inherits from Exception.  For more precise / adapted example, what are you trying to test exactly ?

Comment: Explaining why you need to mock the exception would help to come up with an answer (clearly you have a good reason as `new Exception("bob", innerException)` works just fine)

Comment: @Pac0 I am building my custom `ExceptionFilter`, where I check for some specific `Exception` types and then I execute `logging`, which accepts `Exception` and in some specific scenarios it directly accepts an `InnerException`. I am currently unit testing this filter. But now I ended up, that as you guys suggested, I don't even need to Mock my Exceptions and I can work with pure Exceptions instead of mock, because all I need is to create instantion with its basic properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use Moq for that behavior. Just create an Exception like this:

```
var exception = new Exception("message", new Exception());
```